# Way to see progress when applying dataframe.apply()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am applying a function which transform texts into its tf-idfs, but it seems it takes too much time to build it.
Im thinking if it is possible to see progress of using `.apply()` function

```
people['word_count'] = people['text'].apply(get_ifidf_for_words)
people
```

this is my function where i am applying

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np

people = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/people_wiki1.csv')

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf.fit(list(people['text'].values.tolist()))
feature_names = tfidf.get_feature_names()

def get_ifidf_for_words(text):
    tfidf_matrix= tfidf.transform([text]).todense()
    feature_index = tfidf_matrix[0,:].nonzero()[1]
    tfidf_scores =[tfidf_matrix[0, x] for x in feature_index]
    return tfidf_scores
```

Comment: What is `TfidfVectorizer`? Which package is it from? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Hi, I've added, Although I have completed that `apply` function, although, it came wrong

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. What "came wrong"?

Comment: I was building tf-df vector  of individual texts from sklearn. It is always not working,
I am trying to convert graphlab module to python from coursera. It might not be relevant to this question, but i am asking about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done that once with a work-around:

Redefine the function to

```
def get_ifidf_for_words(row):
    # Progress measurement
    if not row.iat[1] % 5:
        print(f'Progress: {row.iat[1]}%')
    
    # Actual function
    text = row.iat[0]
    tfidf_matrix= tfidf.transform([text]).todense()
    feature_index = tfidf_matrix[0,:].nonzero()[1]
    tfidf_scores =[tfidf_matrix[0, x] for x in feature_index]
    return tfidf_scores
```

and then use `apply` in the following way

```
people['word_count'] = pd.DataFrame(
                            {'text': people['text'].values,
                             'prog': [int(100 * i / people.shape[0])
                                      for i in range(1, people.shape[0]+1)]}
                       ).apply(get_ifidf_for_words, axis='columns')
```

to get progress messages on the console

```
Progress: 5%
Progress: 10%
Progress: 15%
...
```

The logic: You add a progress column to `people['text']` which the function given to `apply` uses to print out the progress.

(I'm not saying it's pretty.)